# Extracting all variables and building a clause?

Tags: variables, prolog

Let say I have a list of facts with unbounded variables :

```
 [f1(a,X),f2(b,Y),f3(Z,c)]
```

how can I extract the variables and create a clause out of it f.e. :

```
 functor(X,Y,Z)
```

may final goal is creating in addition to the above also a rule and asserting it.

```
 functor(X,Y,Z) :- f1(a,X),f2(b,Y),f3(Z,c).
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard `term_variables/2` predicate. For example:

```
| ?- term_variables([f1(a,X),f2(b,Y),f3(Z,c)], Variables).

Variables = [X,Y,Z]

yes
```

Thus something like:

```
new_clause(Goals, Functor, Clause) :-
    list_to_conjunction(Goals, Conjunction),
    term_variables(Conjunction, Variables),
    Head =.. [Functor| Variables],
    Clause = (Head :- Conjunction).
```

You can then assert the constructed clause or add the assert goal to the definition of the `new_clause/3` predicate.